# How to delete any folder matching a name in specific location using batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, delete-file

I have the following directory: `C:\Users\blabla`. Within its tree there are multiple `toDelete` directories, for example:

```
C:\Users\blabla\toDelete
C:\Users\blabla\x1\toDelete
C:\Users\blabla\x2\toDelete
```

I want to remove all these directories regardless of their content.

I tried running:

```bash
@echo off
DEL /Q /F "C:\Users\blabla\**\toDelete"
```

But when I run this script in cmd.exe I get the following error:

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

I also tried running:

```bash
@echo off
set folder_name=toDelete
set folder_path=C:\Users\blabla

for /d %%i in ("%folder_path%\*") do (
    if /i "%%~nxi"=="%folder_name%" (
        DEL /s /q "%%i"
    )
)
```

but got an error:

```
'┬á┬á┬á' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'┬á┬á┬á┬á┬á┬á┬á' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'┬á┬á┬á' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'┬á┬á┬á' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'┬á┬á┬á┬á┬á┬á┬á' is not recognized as an internal command,
operable program or batch file.
```

---

Changed `DEL` to `RD`. Running:

```bash
@echo off
RD /Q "C:\Users\blabla\**\toDelete"
```

And I got this error:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

So I guess the glob pattern here is an issue.

Changed `DEL` to `RD`. Running:

```bash
@echo off
set folder_name="toDelete"
set folder_path="C:\Users\blabla"

for /d %%i in ("%folder_path%\*") do (
    if /i "%%~nxi"=="%folder_name%" (
        RD /s /q "%%i"
    )
)
```

I get empty output, (I guess successful completion), but the directories were not removed.

Comment: `FOR /D` doesn't recurse directory trees; you need to use the `/R`ecurse option to do that!

Comment: In a batch file can be used `for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "%USERPROFILE%\toDelete" /AD-L /B /S 2^>nul') do ECHO rd /Q /S "%%I"`. Please note that this command line with __ECHO__ just outputs the command lines which delete quietly with all subdirectories and files all the `toDelete` directories found by __DIR__ in the current user's profile directory referenced with `%USERPROFILE%` and all its subdirectories. That command line was posted dozens of times on Stack Overflow in many batch file code examples. You are not the first Windows user who wants to delete all directories with a fixed name.

Comment: In addition to the above, as there is a possibility that a directory named `toDelete` could exist within a branch of another directory named `toDelete`, it may also be prudent to change your `Do` portion to ```If /I "%%~nxI" == "toDelete" If Exist "%%I\." ECHO RD /Q /S "%%I"``` too.

Answer (score 0):

I have an attempt, based on `forfiles`. It is not working, but it might with a small correction.

For your information: I've done the same thing as you, but I did it in a `C:\Temp_Folder` directory:

Where are the directories?

```
C:\Temp_Folder>FORFILES /S /M "ToDelete" /C "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE echo @path"

"C:\Temp_Folder\ToDelete"
"C:\Temp_Folder\x1\ToDelete"
"C:\Temp_Folder\x2\ToDelete"
```

Delete them:

```
C:\Temp_Folder>FORFILES /S /M "ToDelete" /C "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE RD /Q @path"

ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.
ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.
ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: Please use never `%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe` (not available on Windows XP by default) if there can be used also the internal command `for` of `cmd.exe`. __FORFILES__ should be used only on using option `/D`. In all other use cases `for` is much better. It is very inefficient to run for each file or folder found by __FORFILES__ one more `cmd.exe` just to do something with that file or folder using one of the internal commands of `cmd.exe`. Starting and terminating 1000 times `cmd.exe` to process 1000 files or folders instead of using just one `cmd.exe` is horrible.

Comment: @Mofi: I agree. As `forfiles` starts up a new command prompt for every occurence, it's better only to use it for small amounts.